# Unity enable/disable boolean while playing (editor)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Best method to listen when checkbox is enabled / disabled (in Unity Editor) ?

I want to enable and disable while running/playing scene

[image]

Maybe possible to toggle once and Editor could wait when i click again?
I don't need every update scan list..

My code:

```
void Update () {
    checkboxStatus(visibleLocations, locationsList);
}

public void checkboxStatus(bool checkboxEnabled, List<GameObject> list)
{
    if (list.Count > 0) 
    {
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (checkboxEnabled)
            {
                item.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply store and compare the previous value. You could **optionally** also add pre-processors in order to make the `Update` method only exist in the editor but later in a build only use the method call (see [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)) like

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private bool _lastVisibleLocations;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if(visibleLocations != _lastVisibleLocations)
        {
            checkboxStatus(visibleLocations, locationsList);
            _lastVisibleLocations = visibleLocations;
        }
    }
#endif

public void checkboxStatus(bool checkboxEnabled, List<GameObject> list)
{
    // You can skip the check for Count here
    // if there are no elements then foreach simply will do nothing anyway
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // your if-else here was a bit redundant 
        // you can directly use the value of checkBoxEnabled
        item.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = checkBoxEnabled;
    }
}
```

If it is only for the Editor you could even move it from `Update` into `OnValidate` so it is only checked if something actually was changed via the Inspector.